# How to calculate average values with integer and decimal?

Tags: java

Here I want average of row5, row6, row7, then I want to check with another table whether calculation is right or wrong. How to achieve this?

```
    for(WebElement rowElement:TotalRowCount)
    {
        List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td/span"));
        int ColumnIndex=1;
        for(WebElement colElement:TotalColumnCount)
        {
            String s=colElement.getText().replace("%", "").replace(",","");
            if(!s.isEmpty()&&!s.equals("NA"))
            {
                if(s.contains(".")||s.contains("-"))
                {
                    double d=Double.parseDouble(s);
                    System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+"Double value is"+d);
                }
                else
                {
                    int x1=Integer.parseInt(s);
                    System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+"Integer value"+x1);
                }

                ColumnIndex=ColumnIndex+1;

            }
            else{/*do nothing*/}
        }
        RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Row 5Integer value140
Row 6Integer value51
Row 6Integer value52
Row 6Integer value51
Row 6Integer value36
Row 7Double value is30.0
Row 7Double value is30.65
Row 7Double value is29.38
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Please spend some time improving your question: A) by properly indenting/formating all of your code and B) by providing explicit information about actual versus *expected* behavior.

Comment: @GhostCat thank you, code works fine but i want to calculate average, how to achieve this

Comment: By computing the sum and dividing by the number of entries? I don't get your question.